# GCC 5+ on CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos, gcc

I was wondering how to get GCC 5+ on CentOS 6.8 and use it as the default compiler. I have seen several answers to this, but all of them point to binaries that are no longer hosted on the internet. I have compiled GCC from scratch for CentOS, but it is not the default GCC on the system so I have to change Makefiles so that they use the compiled dynamic libraries instead of the default ones.